# Shop 'CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront' does not exist

Tags: sitecore-commerce

While installing `Sitecore Commerce 9.1.1`, I got below issue:

[image]

Below issue logged in the Shops `application’s log`:

---

```
/sitecore/api/ssc/item/?path=%2Fsitecore%2FCommerce%2FCommerce%20Control%20Panel%2FStorefront%20Settings%2FStorefronts%2FCommerceEngineDefaultStorefront&database=master&language=en
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionManager.d__15.MoveNext()
00037 22:04:37 ERROR Management.block.getitembypath: Sitecore Item Service Get item failed, Item /sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts/CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront not found.
00037 22:04:37 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.InvalidShop: Text=Shop 'CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront' does not exist.
00047 22:04:37 ERROR PipelineAbort:Shop 'CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront' does not exist.
```

---

It seems that while installing `SXC 9.1.1`, few packages missed installing.

Please, can somebody help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like Commerce Engine doesn't have connection to Sitecore instance. First, please check `CommerceAuthoring_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.Content.PolicySet-1.0.0.json` file, that it contains correct sitecore credentials

Comment: Thanks Andrei. Yes you are right need to change sitecore credentials. but that need to change at 8 places. which i did. but still after running the installation script admin account is getting locked and i am seeing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things fixed my issue and I am able to install SXC 9.1 with Sitecore 9.1.1:

1. Add AllowedCrosOginisGroup in the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXX.identityserver\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml
   [image]
2. Change the admin credentials in the commerce websites (Authering, Minions, Ops, Shops). It contains admin/b but in Sitecore 9.1 onwards you can change the default password. so if you have changed password, change the same credentials here as well.
3. Change the credentials in the SXC installation package as well.